# What is the meaning of 負ける here?

Tags: grammar, meaning

I know 負ける is "to lose" but here it sounds weird.
Main character wants to save someone that also Naoto wants to so he says:

> 俺だってタチバナを救いたいって気持ちは **直人に負けてねえ**

it sounds like "I won't lose Naoto!" but actually he says (in subtitles) "just as much as Naoto"

also why って気持ち is it like (と思う)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's still "to lose" here, you're just getting the subject confused.

In this sentence, 気持ち is what is doing the 負けてねえ, not 俺 - the って気持ち, like you said, is quotative like the と in と思う. A literal translation would be "My feelings (of 俺だってタチバナを救いたい) won't lose to Naoto('s)!"